# ReactJS URL Query String. BrowserHistory not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history

I'm having an issue with the way react-router structures a URL. Currently the URL is giving me this structure for pages:

**Root Component:**
`http://localhost:3000/#/?_k=24zils`
**Contact Component:**
`http://localhost:3000/#/contact?_k=v12iev`
**About Component:**
`http://localhost:3000/#/about?_k=b22bqm`

I'm tyring to get them to display as so:

**Root Component:**
`http://localhost:3000/#/`
**Contact Component:**
`http://localhost:3000/#/contact`
**About Component:**
`http://localhost:3000/#/about`

I was reading about browserHistory which is supported by react-router. It uses the History API built into the browser to manipulate the URL.

**Router file:**

```
//Import Dependencies.
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//Import Components.
import HomeElement from '../views/home/home.jsx';
import ContactElement from '../views/contact/contact.jsx';
import AboutElement from '../views/about/about.jsx';

//Set up routes.
let routes = (
    <Router>
        <Route path='/' component={HomeElement}/>
        <Route path='/about' component={AboutElement}/>
        <Route path='/contact' component={ContactElement}/>
    </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

**Main file:**

```
//Import Dependencies.
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

//Import Routes.
import routes from './routes/routes.js';

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('component-wrapper'));
```

I'm receiving zero errors. Url is still structured using the query parameter. Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?

**Server:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Listening at localhost:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the hash history for react-router, you can set the `queryKey` option to false to disable this behavior, even though it's not recommended.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory'

import routes from './routes/routes.js'

var history = createHistory({ queryKey: false })

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history} routes={routes} />,
  document.getElementById('component-wrapper')
)
```

More info about this [here](http://rackt.org/history/stable/HashHistoryCaveats.html)

Comment: That's going to disable state though right? That's not what I want.

Comment: It's the only way to get rid of the query parameter while using a HashHistory. But are the hash mandatory in your case or you want to use the BrowserHistory?

Comment: I don't want to use hashHistory. That's why i'm trying to set up browserHistory. Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Have you restarted your server after you did the changes mentioned in the [react-router docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server) to handle the new history behavior?

Comment: I just tried rebooting my server. Still receiving the query paramater in the URL.